# How can I evaluate a lazy val using reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection, lazy-evaluation

Using the experimental Scala 2.10 reflection, when I try to call FieldMirror.get() on a field that is a lazy val, it returns null.  Is there a way to evaluate the lazy val using reflection?  The get() function should no longer return null afterwards.

Consider this example:

```
case class Person(val firstName: String,
                  val lastName: String) {
  lazy val name = firstName + " " + lastName
}

import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

val runtimeMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val fred = Person("Fred", "Smith")

val instanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(fred)

val nameTerm = ru.typeOf[Person].declaration(ru.newTermName("name")).asTerm

val nameLazy = instanceMirror.reflectField(nameTerm)

nameLazy.get
    >>> res8: Any = null

fred.name
    >>> res9: String = Fred Smith

nameLazy.get
    >>> res10: Any = Fred Smith
```

Comment: force the evaluation of that lazy expression. i do not know the specifics in scala.

Comment: At this point, I only have a reference to the lazy val - a FieldMirror -  so I can't simply evaluate it.  The get() function returns the expression and then I could easily evaluate it.

Answer (score 7):

I discovered the solution.  There is a hidden method that gets generated:

```
case class Person(val firstName: String,
              val lastName: String) {
 lazy val name = firstName + " " + lastName
}

import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

val runtimeMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val fred = Person("Fred", "Smith")

val instanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(fred)

val nameMethod = ru.typeOf[Person].member(ru.newTermName("name")).asMethod
val nameValue = ru.typeOf[Person].member(ru.newTermName("name")).asTerm

val nameLazy = instanceMirror.reflectField(nameValue)
val nameLazyMethod = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(nameMethod)

nameLazy.get
    >>> null

nameLazyMethod()
    >>> res9: String = Fred Smith

nameLazy.get
    >>> res10: String = Fred Smith
```

Comment: You could also try `ru.typeOf[Person].member(ru.newTermName("name")).asTerm.getter`